# The given path's format is not supported (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, path

Below coding are code that I used to rename and store images at temporary files.

Declaration as below :

```
Dim extension As String = Path.GetExtension(hpf.FileName)
Dim rename As String = Now.ToString(gsUserStation + "ddMMyyHHmmss")
Dim imageRename As String = Path.Combine(rename + extension)
Dim imgUrl As String = Server.MapPath("source") & "\" & Path.Combine(rename + extension)
```

And code to save :

```
hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("source") & "\" & imageRename)
```

This coding working fine but I don't know what happened when I run it sometimes with different code of station, it threw me an error

> The given path's format is not supported.

When I do debugging, the variable **rename** (expectation result : BKI081116120002) became something like `B+08:00I0811160002`. I don't get it, how come the result of station code `BKI` became `B+08:00I`. So that is the one that causing the error to happen.

Any suggestion from you guys? Thank you.

Comment: Presumably the "K" in "BKI" has some special meaning to the `DateTime.ToString` method, just as you already know various other characters do.  Maybe you should read the relevant documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So I've come out with different way which is separating the time and extension. `Dim getDate As String = Now.ToString("ddMMyyHHmmss")` for getting the date and `Dim rename As String = gsUserStation + getDate` for renaming.

Comment: in your rename line you are using '+' for string concatenation. This is ambiguous. Use '&' instead. The following line is wrong too; path.combine takes two args separated by a comma.

Comment: @peterG Thank you for the reply. It helps me to improve my knowledge and programming skills :)